# Comparator in priority queue has error

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue, comparator

Every line in my heap priority queue class have no errors except for the comparator in the HeapPriorityQueue constructor. I don't know how to fix it so there will be no error. I can't even check if the algorithm is working correctly because of the error. Can someone please help me?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class HeapPriorityQueue<K extends Comparable<K>,V> implements PriorityQueue<K,V>     
{
    protected Comparator<K> comp;

    .
    .      //other lines of code
    .

    public HeapPriorityQueue() {
        heap = new ArrayList<Entry<K,V>>();
        heap.add(null);
        comp = new Comparator<K>();      //<-------- with error
    }

    .
    .      //other lines of code
    .

    comp.compare(oneKey,anotherKey);    //<---- using comp here

    .
    .      //other lines of code
    .

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Comparator` is an interface, so you can't instantiate it with `new`. You may use anonymous class delegating the comparison to objects:

```
comp = new Comparator<K>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(K a, K b) {
       return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that compilation error message is self explainable. Line

`comp = new Comparator<K>();`

is an attempt to instantiate interface because `Comparator` is an interface. You should either create your own class that implements comparator or use one of third party classes or create anonymous inner class.